# Is $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_i})\cdot \mathbf{n_i}$ nearly tri-linear near the surface $S=\partial A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set $A\in R^3$, where $S\in \partial A$ is its boundary. Define
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_i})\cdot \mathbf{n_i}
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{x}\in R^3\\
\mathbf{x_i}\in S\\
\mathbf{n_i} \text{ is the unit normal vector at } \mathbf{x_i}
$$
Is $f(\mathbf{x})$ nearly tri-linear when $\mathbf{x}$ is near the surface $S$?